# gcc error while installing asyncio backport trollius (Python 2.7.5 and Win7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-asyncio

I fail to install asyncio backport trollius. From the docs, I have to: "...first build the _overlapped.pyd extension (it will be placed in the asyncio directory):"

```
PS C:\Users\M1330\Downloads\trollius-0.1.6> python setup.py build_ext
running build_ext
building 'asyncio._overlapped' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-2.7
creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
C:\WinPython\tools\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\WinPython\python-2.7.5\include -IC:\WinPython\python-2.7.5\PC -c overlapped.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\overlapped.o
overlapped.c:105:1: error: unknown type name 'LPFN_ACCEPTEX'
overlapped.c:105:36: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
overlapped.c:106:1: error: unknown type name 'LPFN_CONNECTEX'
overlapped.c:106:38: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
overlapped.c:107:1: error: unknown type name 'LPFN_DISCONNECTEX'
overlapped.c:107:44: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
overlapped.c: In function 'initialize_function_pointers':
overlapped.c:118:25: error: 'WSAID_ACCEPTEX' undeclared (first use in this function)
overlapped.c:118:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
overlapped.c:119:26: error: 'WSAID_CONNECTEX' undeclared (first use in this function)
overlapped.c:120:29: error: 'WSAID_DISCONNECTEX' undeclared (first use in this function)
overlapped.c: In function 'overlapped_RegisterWaitWithQueue':
overlapped.c:293:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'RegisterWaitForSingleObject' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
overlapped.c:294:38: error: 'WAITORTIMERCALLBACK' undeclared (first use in this function)
overlapped.c:294:58: error: expected ')' before 'PostToQueueCallback'
overlapped.c: In function 'overlapped_UnregisterWait':
overlapped.c:320:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'UnregisterWait' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
overlapped.c: In function 'Overlapped_dealloc':
overlapped.c:583:21: warning: unknown conversion type character 'R' in format [-Wformat]
overlapped.c:583:21: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
overlapped.c: In function 'Overlapped_AcceptEx':
overlapped.c:959:22: error: called object 'Py_AcceptEx' is not a function
overlapped.c: In function 'Overlapped_ConnectEx':
overlapped.c:1046:23: error: called object 'Py_ConnectEx' is not a function
overlapped.c: In function 'Overlapped_DisconnectEx':
overlapped.c:1086:26: error: called object 'Py_DisconnectEx' is not a function
overlapped.c: In function 'Overlapped_WaitNamedPipeAndConnect':
overlapped.c:1224:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'QueueUserWorkItem' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
overlapped.c: In function '_init_overlapped':
overlapped.c:1410:5: error: 'SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT' undeclared (first use in this function)
overlapped.c: At top level:
overlapped.c:256:1: warning: 'PostToQueueCallback' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
overlapped.c:517:1: warning: 'Overlapped_doc' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Undeclared variables and type name. I know little C, what did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install Microsoft SDK to build Python extensions, see:
http://haypo-notes.readthedocs.org/misc.html#compile-python-extensions-on-windows

Note: I'm the Trollius author. You can contact me by email.

Comment: With the version of trollius uploaded yesterday: 0.2, I was able to install it without MS SDK. That was not the case before. Bounty is for your port of asynco for Python 2, thanks!

Comment: I now distribute wheel packages, Trollius can be easily installed using pip: http://trollius.readthedocs.org/#install-trollius-on-windows-using-pip